# data.getExtras().get("data") result of low resolution image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-intent, image

In my app I take a picture from camera and then I get that picture to do some image processing operations on same picture but when I get this picture with data.getExtras().get("data") , picture come with low resolution not real taken resolution. What can be reason of the problem?

Code is like that;

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(intent , CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data )
    {
        if( requestCode != 0)
        { 
            ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: It could be how you are storing it, or the object type you are using when it is retrieved.  Since we can't see either in your code, we can't tell without seeing these sections of your code.

Comment: @user432209 there is no other code it is all of mine

Comment: The variable "thumbnail" suggests that you want a lower-resolution image.  Did you get this code from a tutorial?  Either way, we will have to see the code that sets the "data" extra var.

Answer (score 13):

Mightier nailed it. Without including extras you only get a small sized image. From the Android documentation:

> public static final String ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
>   Since: API Level 3
>
> Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application capture an image and return it.
>
> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Answer (score 9):

Before broadcasting intent, you should include extras to it:

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
```

where imageFileUri could be output file name on SD card:

```
imageFileUri=Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/picture.jpg");
```

That would save image to known location and after taking image you would be able to process it.